# For Odd continuous functions from s2 to R there exist x s.t. f(x)=g(x)=0

Tags: functions, algebraic-topology, even-and-odd-functions

For two odd continuous functions $f$ and $g$ both from $S^2$ to $\Bbb R$ , there is a $x$ such that $f(x)=g(x)=0$.

Please someone give me a hit about this...

Comment: What do you mean by $S_2$?

Comment: @LukasKofler.  Perhaps it's meant to be $S^2$, considered as a subset of the vector space $\Bbb R^3.$   But  I can't be sure.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet:  I'm  pretty sure that's what OP user470412 meant.

Comment: This is a consequence of the [Borsuk-Ulam theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Borsuk%E2%80%93Ulam_theorem).